# php while loop into for question

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code in my php and would like to understand it better:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo $row['name'];
 }
```

How can I turn this into a "for" loop?  I tried, but I didn't know how to reference the correct row I wanted...$row[$i]['name'] did not work...

EDIT - The goal is to reverse the echo of the output. So the results are the other way...I only know how to do this with for loops using $i-- –

Comment: That's hardly possible...why would you want that?

Comment: The goal is to reverse the echo of the output.  So the results are the other way...I only know how to do this with for loops using $i--

Comment: The more easiest way to reverse the output is to use ORDER BY with or without DESC in your sql query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieve your number of rows using `mysql_num_rows`, then you can use a `for`-loop:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo $row['name'];
}
```

I'd use "mysql_fetch_assoc" for this one.

If you really need to use "[$i]['name']", you need to transfer the rows to an array first:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Now you can access e.g. $row[0]['name'] using a `for`-loop, if you really need to.

EDIT:

> The goal is to reverse the echo of the
>   output.

To do that you can fetch all rows into an array (using `mysq_fetch_assoc` and the above `while`-loop to build the array), use `array_reverse` to reverse the order and then a `foreach`-loop to echo the elements. Still, no `for`-loop needed ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
for(;$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

But why?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this:

```
for ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $row; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $row['name'];
}
```

In this approach you do not need to use $i variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (;;) {
    if (!($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
        break;
    }
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Seriously though, you *can't* use a `for` loop here. `mysql_fetch_array` only gives you the *next* row as long as there are rows. As you correctly said, there's no index to refer to, hence not much use of looping over an index.

> The goal is to reverse the echo of the output.

You do this in your query with an `ORDER BY ... DESC`/`ASC` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The trick in this `while` construct is that the iteration stops when the assignment “fails”, i.e. [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) returns `false` as there are no (further) rows and thus the assignment returns `false` too.

To use a `for` instead of this `while` construct, you could use [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/mysql_result) instead of `mysql_fetch_array` to get a specific row from the result set:

```
for ($i=0, $n=mysql_num_rows($result); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_result($result, $i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the order using database.

> select * from table **ORDER BY** field **DESC**